# How can we get all the partial definitions of a partial type in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

For a C# program, how can we get all the partial definitions of a partial type in Visual Studio 2015?

Is it by checking all the references of the type name, and then manually check each reference if it is a partial definition of itself?

Is there a more direct way?

Does the class view of a partial class give the complete definition of a class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Right click the class name, "Go To Definition" (or put the cursor on the class name and hit F12), you will then get a find symbol result of the definitions.

And yes, class view does give the entire defintion

Comment: ...and when you're in a class source file, the methods pull-down will show the methods defined in "other files" of the partial class as a touch greyed-out. Find-in-files (Ctrl+Shift+F) for *class MyClassName* will show you where all the partial class files are.

Answer (score 0):

Partial classes are syntactic sugar for dividing generated and programmer created code for one class. After compilation all parts will be combined to one class.

Comment: I don't think the OP asked what a partial class was?